# upon refresh redirect to a url from apicontroller in mvc4 angularjs application

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have programmed WebAPI project, using asp.net, using angularjs and bootstrap.

I have mvc4 apicontroller class as follows:

```
    public class ProfileController : ApiController
    {
        private IReminderDb _db;

        public ProfileController(IReminderDb db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

......
}
```

When I type the following in the browser

```
http://localhost:3458/#/Profile
```

It successfully navigates to the profile page as expected.

But when I hit the refresh page, I want to know which event inside the apicontroller I could capture this so I could redirect to the following url

```
http://localhost:3458/#/Profile
```

Comment: Part after # is controller by client side router service not from server.

Comment: Why you want to redirect from server?..while client side routing has this feature.

Comment: pankaj, where on client side , in angularjs , I can control this from?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a get method which you call from your profile page, you can hit there once you request a profile data from web api. But I believe you can do what you want to do in a better way from client side.

```
// api/profiles/1
[HttpGet]
public Profile Get()
{

}
```